# In Fallout Shelter, is it better to send max equipment Level 1 dwellers over Level 50 into the Wastelands?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Starting out in Fallout Shelter, we got lucky and opened a MIRV in one of our first few packs. We equipped it on a Level 1 character and sent him into the Wastelands. We discovered that every time he leveled - his health reset. The result was that he lasted for days. He rarely had to use his health stims because he kept leveling. When he returned he was level 50.

It seems like a Level 1 character with maximum equipment and stats might be more efficient than sending a level 50 character into the Wastelands because of the health stim savings.

The question is - is there really any advantage to sending out a level 50 character into the Wastelands? Do they truly last longer than a Level 1 character sent out with maximum equipment given the health stim savings difference? Or is it really just better just to send out maxed stat, maxed equipment Level 1 dwellers?

Answer (score 5):

No, not really. As you already stated, the health of the Dweller always resets when they level, that means they will already last (roughly) 50 times longer, even without the Stimpacks.

The downside is that you only have a finite amount of low level dwellers, but an unlimited Stimpack production. The other catch is that every Dweller, regardless of their level, has a finite amount of storage, So they will return once their carry weight has been reached, regardless of level.

This is all up to chance though, too. There is a chance they might not get enough experience to level up properly, and not find any loot, so they may still die. That chance is fairly small though.